# Trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center, tor

Whenever I try to open Ubuntu Software Center it says my files are corrupted, when I click repair, it says,

```
Package operation failed
      The installation or removal of a software package failed
Details
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 255659 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tor_0.2.4.20-1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking tor (0.2.4.20-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.20-1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/tor', which is also in package tor-browser 3.5.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/tor_0.2.4.20-1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vidalia:
 vidalia depends on tor (>= 0.2.2.29-beta-1); however:
  Package tor is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package vidalia (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tor-geoipdb:
 tor-geoipdb depends on tor (>= 0.2.4.20-1); however:
  Package tor is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package tor-geoipdb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Comment: Did you just try to install Tor recently?

Comment: yes, yesterday morning, now it just dose this.

Comment: Try purging (`apt-get purge`) anything related to Tor as it is conflicting with itself.

Comment: I think the command I would issue is `sudo apt-get remove --purge tor*`

Comment: okay, now it is saying it requires me to install untrusted packages, the one it is wanting me to install is tor,and then tells me "New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?" when I click repair the messages repeat. this is all after following both of your suggestions.

Comment: Well, we're getting closer!  How did you try to install Tor - I think we want to back that out of your system for the time being.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I would generally recommend against things like `sudo apt-get remove --purge tor*`, and recommend `sudo apt-get remove --purge tor-*` (with a `-*`) instead. The `*` ignores the character right before it, so it will purge anything beginning with `to`, at least IIRC.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I think, to be more specific, APT commands recognize regex, where `*` means "zero or more of the preceding character" but if the expression is not quoted, the shell will expand the wildcard if it can match anything, so the result depends on whether you get a match or not. I agree with your recommendation, but it may be better to use regex for reliable results: `sudo apt-get remove --purge 'tor-.*'` for example

Comment: @Zanna you are the expert on this sort of stuff. I just read an article somewhere that explained a little bit about what it did. I'll start recommending and using that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This solution worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg -r tor-browser tor-geoipdb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Run these commands to install TOR:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```